# Support arbitrary combination of AND, OR, NOT in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, parsing, elasticsearch, lexer

I have an application which wants to expose the API to query Arbitary AND OR NOT queries to the user. The user should be able to give me a string which any number of AND, OR and NOT phrases. The rules for nesting should be parenthesis and normal precedence rules should apply.
As an Eg.

query= ( (Abhishek AND Vaid) OR ( Abhishek AND Vaids) ) AND NOT (Abhishek AND Vaider) should be a valid query.
The Rules for operators are as following:

- I'm defining three operators here:" AND "," OR ",and" NOT ". (these are AND, OR and NOT.
- The " NOT " is unary and " AND " and " OR " is binary. " NOT " has
  higher precedence over other two.

Is there a way for me to do this out of the box from Java Driver in ES ? Please note that I can always convert such a query in nested boolean, but I don't want to write a lexer and parser to create a parse tree by scratch and then resolve it to a complex boolean DSL. **I'm looking for some existing functionality to achieve this**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're giving your users the power to create those queries themselves, you can never be sure what they will input. `query_string` will work but will most likely throw exceptions if your users provide syntactically incorrect queries.

For that reason, another query was created, namely [`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#_simple_query_string_syntax), which is semantically equivalent to `query_string`, but will never throw any exceptions and discard whatever syntax errors your users are making.

Plus, in addition, it is possible to enable only the operators you want using the `flags` setting, i.e. AND (`+`), OR (`|`) and NOT (`-`).

```
{
  "simple_query_string" : {
    "fields" : ["content"],
    "query" : "this + that | other -another",
    "flags" : "AND|OR|NOT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's possible. If I understood you correctly, you need [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Taken from documentation:

> A query that uses a query parser in order to parse its content. Here
>   is an example:
>
> ```
> {
>   "query_string" : {
>     "default_field" : "content",
>     "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
>   }
> }
> ```

You should figure out how to implement your logic using this.